# How to multiply dataframe in effective way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':list('abcde')})
```

I want to make duplicate of dataframe by length of its contents.

Basically I want to get each value in col1 to be added with entire contents of col2.

Input:

```
   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
4     5    e
```

O/P:

```
    col1 col2
0      1    a
1      1    b
2      1    c
3      1    d
4      1    e
5      2    a
6      2    b
7      2    c
8      2    d
9      2    e
10     3    a
11     3    b
12     3    c
13     3    d
14     3    e
15     4    a
16     4    b
17     4    c
18     4    d
19     4    e
20     5    a
21     5    b
22     5    c
23     5    d
24     5    e
```

For this I have used this,

```
op=[]
for val in df.col1.values:
    temp=df.copy()
    temp['col1']=val
    op.append(temp)
print(pd.concat(op,ignore_index=True))
```

I want to get exact output in a better way(excluding loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with unstack :

```
pd.DataFrame(index=df.col2,columns=df.col1).unstack().reset_index().drop(0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cross join and filter necessary columns:

```
df = pd.merge(df.assign(a=1), df.assign(a=1), on='a')[['col1_x','col2_y']]
df = df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
print (df)
    col1 col2
0      1    a
1      1    b
2      1    c
3      1    d
4      1    e
5      2    a
6      2    b
7      2    c
8      2    d
9      2    e
10     3    a
11     3    b
12     3    c
13     3    d
14     3    e
15     4    a
16     4    b
17     4    c
18     4    d
19     4    e
20     5    a
21     5    b
22     5    c
23     5    d
24     5    e
```

Comment: I need in the same order also.

Comment: there are only 2 columns?

Comment: in col1 value must be 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,...5,5,5. in your case it comes as 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5...

Answer (score 1):

try itertools to do that

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':list('abcde')})

res = pd.DataFrame((product(df['col1'],df['col2'])),columns=['col1','col2'])
print(res)
```

```
    col1 col2
0      1    a
1      1    b
2      1    c
3      1    d
4      1    e
5      2    a
6      2    b
7      2    c
8      2    d
9      2    e
10     3    a
11     3    b
12     3    c
13     3    d
14     3    e
15     4    a
16     4    b
17     4    c
18     4    d
19     4    e
20     5    a
21     5    b
22     5    c
23     5    d
24     5    e
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want is the cartesian product. I would do it like this:

```
from intertools import product
pd.DataFrame(product(*[df.col1.values,df.col2.values]),columns=["col1","col2"])

#output
    0   1
0   1   a
1   1   b
2   1   c
3   1   d
4   1   e
5   2   a
6   2   b
7   2   c
8   2   d
9   2   e
10  3   a
11  3   b
12  3   c
13  3   d
14  3   e
15  4   a
16  4   b
17  4   c
18  4   d
19  4   e
20  5   a
21  5   b
22  5   c
23  5   d
24  5   e
```

You need to input the name of the columns again, thou.

Comment: your proposed answer is similar to the @tawab_shakeel answer, any way +1

Answer (score 1):

Well..essentially anything that gives you cartesian product would do. For example,

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['col1'],df['col2']]).to_frame(index=False, name=['Col1','Col2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':list('abcde')})

# repeat col1 values
df_col1 = df['col1'].repeat(df.shape[0]).reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)
# multiply col2 values
df_col2 = pd.concat([df['col2']]*df.shape[0], ignore_index=True)
# contact results
result = pd.concat([df_col1, df_col2], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Output:

```
    col1 col2
0      1    a
1      1    b
2      1    c
3      1    d
4      1    e
5      2    a
6      2    b
7      2    c
8      2    d
9      2    e
10     3    a
11     3    b
12     3    c
13     3    d
14     3    e
15     4    a
16     4    b
17     4    c
18     4    d
19     4    e
20     5    a
21     5    b
22     5    c
23     5    d
24     5    e
```